# How do I attach python code (script) to execute at specific frame in the timeline?

Tags: scripting, keyframes

I want to programmatically replace images every time a playing animation hits a specific frame in the timeline.

If my script monitors the current frame I could use something like this...

```
def frame_handler():
    if bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 42:
        do something here
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #bpy.utils.register_class(Frame_handler)
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(frame_handler)
```

But, I'm hoping there's a more elegant way that I'm missing.  Perhaps there's a way to attach python scripts to arbitrary points in the timeline?

Comment: That frame change handler seems the most straight forward way of implementing this. What part of this solution isn't elegant enough for you?

Comment: @rjg what part isn't elegant? >> Having to hard code the frame number means that changes become a bit more onerous - if the script were attached to a frame (like a keyframe is) then it could be revised without touching the code.